# Inserting current date into sql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to insert the current date using the `now()` syntax but it's not working. The column in MySQL is under `datetime` called `date_added` but when I check the command prompt all I get is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

```
INSERT INTO FOOD (food_name, food_type, total, available, date_added)
VALUES
('$_POST[food_name]','$_POST[food_type]','$_POST[total]','$_POST[available]','NOW()')";
```

Comment: You should be using prepared statements to prevent against SQL injection. Otherwise, you will end up like Bobby.

Comment: array keys should always be quoted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the single quotes from `NOW()`:

```
...
VALUES (
$_POST[food_name],
$_POST[food_type],
$_POST[total],
$_POST[available],
NOW())";
```

Comment: I was a bit confused too, but the whole thing is a string in double quotes. The quotes around the $_POST should stay because those are SQL quotes. Not very beautiful though.

Comment: Dont forget to set the quotes in the post value: $_POST['name_from_input_field']

Comment: Thank you, it's always the minor issues that have me stumped! will change the quotes too thanks user3158490

Answer (score 5):

Remove the quotes around NOW(), in that way NOW() is treated as a SQL function instead of a string.

```
VALUES ('$_POST[food_name]','$_POST[food_type]','$_POST[total]','$_POST[available]',NOW())";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if the following option works:

```
GETDATE()
```

Comment: Why a GETDATE()? Removing the quotes is more then enough right?

Answer (score -1):

offtopic:

Is this possible with the array? Never gave it a shot:

```
$food= array('apple', 'Banana', 'Pineapple');

INSERT INTO food ('fruit_arrays') VALUES ($food)
```